# How do I test sending an email with Django registration on a local computer (Mac 10.7)?

Tags: python, django, email, smtp, django-registration

I never tried sending emails programmatically before. Do I need to set up a SMTP server on my local machine or something? Or can I use someone else's SMTP server (maybe Gmail's)?

Everytime Django registration is trying to send an email I get the error `[Errno 61] Connection refused`.

Here is the [traceback](http://dpaste.com/717553/). And a partial screenshot of the error screen:

[image]

I would appreciate any introductory explanations or beginner tutorials with Django and emails. Thanks!

Comment: Actually  in tests it's best not to rely on any remote servers. I recommend monkey patching SMTP module and storing the emails in some variable instead of sending them. That would allow you to not only make sure they are sent out but also what are the contents.

Comment: Instead of monkey patching, you can simply use the [dummy backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#dummy-backend).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [basics of email sending](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/) are detailed quite well in the documentation. For development purposes - a [dummy backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#dummy-backend) is provided; it basically acts like a email server so you can validate your email sending logic.

Comment: I have used EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend' to show all messages in console